# image = ImageTk.PhotoImage with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So basically, I want to open an Image with `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage()` and it works fine with

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/timol/PycharmProjects/Test1/haha.jpg")
```

Earlier in the code I saved a path in a variable which is

```
def click():
    file = askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/%s')
    directory = os.path.split(file)[0]
    print(directory)
```

Now, I want to use the path saved in "directory" to put in `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file= "directory")`
But it just gives me a lot of errors.

In case you need to know, I want to do that, because I want the User later on to be able to upload an image and display/use in the program.

here's the entire code:

```
`from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
import PIL
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Zahlenerfassung")
root.geometry("500x400")
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
def create(): command=os.system("start "+"pepsi.txt")
#def click():
    # Get the file
   # file = askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/%s')
    # Split the filepath to get the directory
#  directory = os.path.split(file)[0]
#   print(directory)

def click():
     image_file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/%s")
     image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=image_file_location)
     canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=image, anchor=NW)

button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Bild auswerten", fg="red")
button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Erstelle ein Bild", fg="blue", command=lambda: create())
button3 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Lade dein Bild hoch", fg="blue", command=lambda: click())

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(expand=NO, fill=NONE)

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)

one = Label(root, text="", fg="white")
one.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is `askopenfilename`? Can you add the definition for this function?

Comment: @amanb askopenfilename is a standard builtin tkinter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Zahlenerfassung")
root.geometry("500x400")
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
def create():
    command=os.system("start "+"pepsi.txt")

def click():
     image_file_location = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/%s")
     img = Image.open(image_file_location)
     canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS))     #  this line is for resizing the image to fit canvas size
     # canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)   #  you have to use this line instead of the upper line if you don't want resizing
     canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.image, anchor='nw')

button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Bild auswerten", fg="red")
button2 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Erstelle ein Bild", fg="blue", command=lambda: create())
button3 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Lade dein Bild hoch", fg="blue", command=lambda: click())

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(expand=NO, fill=NONE)

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)

one = Label(root, text="", fg="white")
one.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've added the code to my question. I tried your filedialog but when I select the image in the explorer and open it, the explorer closes but the image doesn't show in the program

Comment: @tim0cy okay now I have your full code, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `askopenfile()` & its `name` attribute to get the filename. `PhotoImage` accepts an image file of type `Image.open()`. I've tested this code and the image appears inside the canvas window.

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk, Canvas, NW, NO, NONE, mainloop
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack(expand=NO, fill=NONE)
image_file_loc = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=r'C:\Users')
file_path = image_file_loc.name
image = Image.open(file_path)
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(50, 50, image=tk_image, anchor=NW)
mainloop()
```

Comment: And how do I display the picture in my canvas? Or generally in my GUI